# Log in using SSH without password

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell, scp

On my server, I've got openssh-server and a special account without password. I'm creating a shell script, that must be used without user input. For example

```
$(ssh dummyUser@dummy.com)
```

I need script to end after signing in. How to do it? (I know about authorised keys).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Account with no password is quite dangerous. Try to use key authorization like that:

```
$(ssh -u dummyUser -i keyfile dummy.com /path/to/the/some_script_on_the_dummy_com.sh)
```

And remember that for unattended login your keypair should not be protected by password.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21467504/819417):

```
a@A:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa
a@A:~> ssh-copy-id b@B
a@A:~> ssh b@B
```

If `ssh-copy-id` is unavailable, use [this](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html):

```
a@A:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa
a@A:~> ssh b@B mkdir -p .ssh
a@A:~> cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
a@A:~> ssh b@B
```

To end a session, use the `exit` command.